# Azure: unable to include extension

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-linux

So I'm trying to deploy a Laravel app to azure and it worked fine at the start. In this project, I need to use SOAP so I included the SoapWrapper package in my Laravel app. When however I try to deploy it to Azure after adding SoapWrapper, I get the following message:

[image]

This says that the soap module and the PHP version are not compatible. However, when I ssh into my Linux server and grab the PHP API I get the same one as the one of the modules:

[image]

I am kind of lost on how to fix this and why this happens.
Also, the path

```
/opt/php/7.3.27/ini/php.ini
```

which is stated on the first picture doesn't exist in my linux server.
Any help or suggestions?